# Keycloak custom login page with `Authorization Code` flow

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-nodejs-connect

we're trying to integrate keycloak with native app but the login/registration oauth2 flow with keycloak presents the default login page which doesn't fit our requirements about material design user screens

I see that there are few options to customise the login screen :

1. Customise the theme provided by keycloak or Deploy new theme to JBoss
2. Add a nodejs api-server to interact with mobile app and use `keycloak.grantManager.obtainDirectly` API but this uses `grantType=password` in `keycloak-connect` package - [keycloak-connect](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect)
   More information about [obtainDirectly](http://www.keycloak.org/keycloak-nodejs-auth-utils/grant-manager.js.html#obtainDirectly)

The first option is bit tedious so we have implemented the second option, but that comes with `grantType=password` flow which is not recommended by oauth

I would like to know if there is any solution from keycloak to use custom login with `Authorization Code`

Comment: Found any solution for this? I also want to route to custom login page in authorization code flow grant type.